# idea read pom.xml-- Read for a long time

Tags: java

[image]

When I opened the idea today, I found that I had been reading pom. XML, and I couldn't open two Windows, otherwise I would get stuck and I had to kill the process.It's no use to reload the idea, and it's no use getting rid of the localhost mappings in the host file.

Answer (score 0):

1.maybe you can resize the vm memory in /bin/idea64.exe.vmoptions

Comment: -Xms1024m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow  17/5000  

I am now in this configuration, but there is still a problem.